# How to call method with data object of deployed application from another application through RMI?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, rmi, gwt-rpc

I have two java applications deployed on apache tomcat, At one stage in my first application needs to communicate with other, i.e. I want to call servlet or method having data object of other application.
Using RMI is it possible??
I want to send some data to the remote method where it is processed and will return some result back to calling application.
So how can I communicate with other application...?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use RMI for communicating among Servlet. There are better/cleaner ways of doing this like calling the Servlet by its URL. You can use [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)/[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) for the same.

Comment: I want to send some data objects from first application to other application's servlet...Is this possible through HTTP..??

Comment: How does you servlet (which you want to call) accepts the data object ?

Comment: Servlet or any class whichever is usefull...I dont have any idea about RMI...I just want to send data and do the specific operatins there..

Answer (score 0):

Servlets can make or understand only HTTP calls. If you are willing to call some methods directly you can use RMI. Create a object, register it with rmi registry at some port, at other end fetch the serilized object and type cast to same class and use it. Regular RMI type